# How can I make a MD5 digest with Javascript var values in my ERB template?

Tags: javascript, ruby, erb

I need to make a signature to pass as param into a jQuery `$.post` AJAX request, but I have some values to be hashed into Javascript vars. Any way to do it in an ERB file? Example:

```
var signature = '<%= Digest::MD5.hexdigest "app_key" + form params + "secret" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normally will be done in client side

```
var signature = md5('app_key' + form_params + 'secret');
```

`md5` is function from other javascript library like [md5.js](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html)